# Change siblings li background color for bootstrap 3 dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, background-color, twitter-bootstrap-3

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li>
            <a href="#about">User01</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#contact">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">
             Dropdown
            <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">User Control01</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">User Control02</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">User Control03</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
         </li>
         <li>
             <a href="#contact">Link</a>
         </li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

When clicked **Dropdown** link change **User01** and **Profile** li background color I want like this;

[image]

Dropdown Link clicked;

[image]

How can I do this with bootstrap 3 dropdown menu?

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle bootstraps `.active` class for the previous siblings:

```
$(".dropdown").click(function(){
    $this).prevAll().toggleClass("active");
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/362/

Comment: This works well since there is no CSS previous sibling selector.

Comment: Works but when clicked field except arrow background-color not change

Comment: when you clicked dropdown, li background color changing but if you clicked a blank field of page, background color not change